# Could not load File of Assembly UnityEngine.UI, Also Editor UI has problems at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im receiving this error:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'UnityEngine.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

Along with

```
Failed to load CustomEditor inspected type
UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes:FindCustomEditorType(Object, Boolean)
```

And my Unity Editor then has problems where the dropdown menus disappear and I have to manually enter string tags. It's fine when I first reopen it but then during runtime it reverts back.

I think this might be due to an update issue. Not sure how to resolve.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating new project to see if this error is still there?

Comment: Maybe your UnityEnginUI.dll is not readable from the installation path? Have you tried recreating a new project, or reinstalling unity?

Answer (score 1):

While I never cought the exact reason why it happens doing 'Reimport All' solves it a lot of the times